# How to multiply the subsets from table?

Tags: matlab, matrix, uitableview, matlab-guide

I have two figures of table.

One table is call H and another one call C. Both table is 4 by 3 table.

So if the user insert a value in two edit box. For example:

```
A = *value*
B = *value*
```

Then the user insert the data in H table. The user only use 2 rows. Let say this is the data:

```
      ALPHA   BETA   GAMMA
H1

H2

H3

H4
```

So the user want to get the subset of H1 and multiply with A and subsets of H2 multiply with B. This is how it will be:

```
C1 = (ALPHA VALUE)*A  (BETA VALUE)*A  (GAMMA VALUE)*A

C2 = (ALPHA VALUE)*B  (BETA VALUE)*B  (GAMMA VALUE)*B
```

Then the user wants to display the answer on C table where it will become like this:

```
            ALPHA        BETA       GAMMA
C1        NEW VALUE    NEW VALUE   NEW VALUE

C2        NEW VALUE    NEW VALUE   NEW VALUE

C3

C4
```

How can i make the coding of this problem?

I have already try this coding but it seems i failed. CAN ANYONE HELP ME PLEASE!!

```
H = cell2mat(get(handles.Mytable3,'Data'));
cost1 = str2num(get(handles.input2_editText,'String'));

cost2 = str2num(get(handles.input3_editText,'String'));

H1 = H(1,:)*cost1;
H2 = H(2,:)*cost2;
H = mat2cell([H1 H2]);
cost = get(H,'Data');
set(handles.Mytable2,'Data',cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
H = num2cell([H1 H2]);
set(handles.Mytable2,'Data',H)
```